# Inside a docker container detach or daemon it without keyboard input

Tags: docker, containers, detach

When inside of a docker container, is there a way of using script/command to detach or send it to daemon process, without any keyboard input? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code that's running inside the container?  What would "detach" mean from your application code's point of view?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.